# How to configure OWIN Selfhost and CORS

Tags: cors, owin

I am trying to understand why my code is working :-)
perhaps a good problem to have.

On my local machine, I have a OWIN/SelfHost WebAPI process running.
I have done nothing specific to CORS and specifically I commented out

```
// appbuilder.useCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)
```

I have a web page on a remote machine, and in the page script it tries to 
access the local machine's web API.

What is surprising is that the api has no issues working, but I expected it 
to fail, because I am not allowing any CORS. The browser indeed sends an Origin header, but what makes the OWIN Self host to accept such a request?

To be clear the remote machines webpage calls http://localhost:9999/Controller/Action and I wonder if the "localhost" has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well.......
You need to add appbuilder.useCors **before** the use webAPI.